# Why gnu make ( (makefile) in MSYS2 parse the @file (file name prefixed with an at symbol) in recipe command line arguments

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, msys2

The Makefile:

```
all:
    @echo -e "foo\nbar" > args.txt
    echo @args.txt
    echo "@args.txt"
```

Run it, the output is:

```
$ make
echo @args.txt
foo bar
echo "@args.txt"
@args.txt
```

It looks like make (or something else?) parses "@param.txt", reads the contents from "param.txt", then use them as command line arguments.

The make I use is GNU make 4.4 under Windows MSYS2.
I also tested GNU make 4.3 under Linux, it does not parse the "@param.txt".

Is this some undocumented feature of make?

Comment: No repro on Make 4.4.1 on Linux, so this not something introduced in 4.4. What if you run `echo @args.txt` directly from MSYS2 bash?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `echo @args.txt` just echo "@args.txt"

Comment: Interesting. Back to the makefile, are you running it with `make` or `mingw32-make`? I'd try both.

Comment: There are some tools (e.g. `gcc`) that have this handling of `@` built in, but I'm not sure why Make would force it for all executables...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's actually `/clang64/bin/mingw32-make.exe`, but I also tried another version of gnu make on windows, it also parses @args.txt

Comment: Did you try `/usr/bin/make.exe` that can be installed with `pacman -S make`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Interesting, `/usr/bin/make` does not parse @args.txt, so it's some problem related to cygwin/ucrt/msvcrt?

Comment: It's probably just `mingw32-make` being jank, I've had [other issues](https://github.innominds.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/17735) with it. But since it's much faster than `make`, I'd still support it in your makefiles.